# How to get the GPU info?

Tags: command-line, graphics, gpu

I'm looking for a command that would give me the same info as:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Except for the GPU (type of the chip and memory, frequency).

Comment: what does: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`  do? what info are you looking for?

Comment: @CharlieParker it outputs information of the cpu...

Comment: I personally use: `python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0));"`

Answer (score 175, accepted):

That type of information is non-standard, and the tools you will use to gather it vary widely.

The command `glxinfo` will give you all available OpenGL information for the graphics processor, including its vendor name, if the drivers are correctly installed.

To get clock speed information, there is no standard tool.

- For ATI/AMD GPUs running the old Catalyst driver, `aticonfig --odgc` should fetch the clock rates, and `aticonfig --odgt` should fetch the temperature data. I'm not familiar with AMDGPU-Pro, but a similar tool should exist.
- For NVIDIA GPUs, the `nvidia-smi` tool will show all of the information you could want, including clock speeds and usage statistics.

I am not aware of an equivalent tool for the open source drivers or for Intel or other GPUs, but other information on the hardware can be fetched from the `lspci` and `lshw` tools.

Comment: How to install glxinfo?

Comment: @stiv: It's part of the Mesa library, and comes with the package `mesa-utils` on Ubuntu.

Comment: `aticonfig` doesn't appear to be available since the retirement of fglrx.  `nvclock` also appears to have been abandoned since the last version was for trusty.  Do you have any updated solutions? Here's [what I have](https://askubuntu.com/a/985237/225694) so far..

Comment: `glxinfo | grep "Device"` worked well enough for me on an Intel GPU

Comment: I use: `glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'`

Comment: All these `grep`s yield “llvmpipe” on my system. Very odd model …

Comment: @stiv `glxinfo` can be installed using the command : `sudo apt install mesa-utils`

Comment: nvidia-smi will show stats as well to include GB size.

Comment: `lspci` did the trick for me.

Comment: `nvidia-smi` is only an option if the driver is installed from what I know. In case of not wanting to use the driver (e.g. libvirt and PCI passthrough of the GPU) this is not possible since the GPU is detatched from the host.

Comment: nvidia-smi was the best option for me.

Answer (score 401):

I do not know of a direct equivalent, but **lshw** should give you the info you want, try:

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

(it also works without `sudo` but the info may be less complete/accurate)

You can also install the package `lshw-gtk` to get a GUI.

Comment: Had to put gksu before the command in the menu to get lshw-gtk to work.

Comment: Any updates? I'm a fan of the command but the only clock rate (frequency) it seems to provide for me is the base bus clock 33MHz. I'm attempting to bring this Q&A up to date. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, new to Deep Learning.  What should it say if I have a GPU?  It says `product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller`

Comment: @Nathan That means that you have a GPU....probably a very weak GPU. Your GPU says `integrated graphics`, which means that it's integrated into the CPU. Your CPU has it own component which functions as a graphics card and probably (to save on costs) uses the ordinary RAM to store its buffers. You do not have a separate independent removable graphics card.

Comment: This doesn't (always?) give the memory for discrete NVidia cards on certain laptops (like the HP G7 Firefly)

Answer (score 149):

A blog post focusing on work done on the command-line is here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-linux-vga-video-card-ram/

Find out the device ID:

```
 lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1
03:00.0
```

You can then use this output with `lspci` again, forming **two nested commands**

```
lspci  -v -s  $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)
```

If you have more than 1 GPU card, try this equivalent command instead:

`lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}`

Output from my system:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 295] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 062e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at ec000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Memory at f4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc80 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7e00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

EDIT: You can avoid the `<access denied>` by launching with `sudo`

So, `(prefetchable) [size=64M)` indicates that I have a 64-MB NVIDIA card. However, I don't, it's rather 256 MB. Why?  See below.

To see how to get the most info and performance out of it, read an extremely comprehensive article on the Arch-Linux Wiki

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA

For **nvidia users**, start with

```
nvidia-smi
```

(This works with the Nvidia drivers installed,but not with systems running the open-source 'nouveau' driver).

Output

```
Thu Dec 19 10:54:18 2013       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 5.319.60   Driver Version: 319.60         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro NVS 295      Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   73C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |      252MB /   255MB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This indicates that I have a 256  MB GDDR3 Graphics card.

At this time, I don't know how to get this for Intel and AMD/ATI GPUs.

Comment: +1 for `nvidia-smi` (that should be highlighted a bit in my opinion)

Comment: If anyone have any idea: [nvidia-smi hangs indefinitely: what could be the issue?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255658/16704)

Comment: `nvidia-smi` not showing me full GPU name.

Comment: `nvidia-smi -q`, [as suggested by @Quanlong](https://askubuntu.com/a/929163/432288) uses more sensible output format.

Comment: You can also use `$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv` to just get the GPU name

Answer (score 90):

Run `google-chrome` and navigate to the URL `about:gpu`.
If chrome has figured out how to use OpenGL, you will get extremely detailing information about your GPU.

Comment: This also works in [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/Home) (`chromium-browser`).

Comment: Clever. Along these lines I additionally went to chromeexperiments.com to see the performance there. Smooth as butter - I'm definitely on gpu

Answer (score 66):

Because you specified a command like `cat` for CPU's this is therefore the equivalent for GPU's.  Specifically for Nvidia cards.  It requires no software except the Nvidia device driver to be loaded.

The path here works for the cards I have.  But yours may differ as others have pointed out in the comments.

1st GPU

```
> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0/information
Model:       GeForce GTX 680
IRQ:         24
GPU UUID:    GPU-71541068-cded-8a1b-1d7e-a093a09e9842
Video BIOS:      80.04.09.00.01
Bus Type:    PCIe
DMA Size:    40 bits
DMA Mask:    0xffffffffff
Bus Location:    0000:01.00.0
```

2nd GPU

```
> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/1/information
Model:       GeForce GTX 580
IRQ:         33
GPU UUID:    GPU-64b1235c-51fc-d6f1-0f0e-fa70320f7a47
Video BIOS:      70.10.20.00.01
Bus Type:    PCIe
DMA Size:    40 bits
DMA Mask:    0xffffffffff
Bus Location:    0000:08.00.0
```

Comment: Thanks! (though`cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000\:01\:00.0/information` for me)

Comment: This is the only correct answer in on-demand cloud/HPC cluster environment on which glxinfo or lspci both fail (the former because there's no OpenGL and display, the latter because the nVidia graphics card is abstracted by a graphics controller like Matrox G200eW3). The folder name under gpus is `0000:3b:00.0` or `0000:d8:00.0` for me, so we should type: `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:3b:00.0/information`. The lovely `Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB` model shows that the `qsub` job limit is satisfied as desired.

Answer (score 34):

For Nvidia cards, type

```
nvidia-smi -q
```

Comment: This got me the UUID of the Nvidia GPU on Windows. Thanks! Really useful!

Answer (score 28):

**clinfo**

```
sudo apt-get install clinfo
clinfo
```

is the analogue of `glxinfo` but for OpenCL, my GPU setup is described at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/how-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu/33483311#33483311 The output contains my GPU model among other things:

```
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Quadro M1200
```

**Ubuntu 20.04 Settings -> About**

You can either open settings by clicking on top right menu, or you can just do:

- Super key (AKA Windows key)
- Type "about" and select the entry

So under "Graphics" I can see that my GPU model is

> Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2

[image]

Some other things it can show:

- "Software Rendering" (Ubuntu 23.10): graphics card not working at all
- "NV117": I think this means it is using Nouveau

**nvidia-settings**

Mixes runtime with some static info.

[image]

More details: [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card/692412#692412)

Comment: This is perfect -- this answer deserved more upvotes. I think the other answers were more catered towards lower-level technical information about the GPU, whereas this option is much more consumer-friendly (since it resembles the Nvidia Control Panel program everyone on Windows is familiar with).

Answer (score 13):

I do believe the best option for this is [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch).

```
# Get neofetch
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dawidd0811/neofetch
sudo apt update
sudo apt install neofetch
# Run neofetch
neofetch
```

This gives an output like this:[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the video card frequency and memory in this answer. There are far simpler methods to obtain the model of GPU which appears to be all you are giving us. I'm not sure what this adds to the existing answers.

Comment: The `screenfetch` program does the same thing and doesn't require a PPA to install.

Comment: It's a shell script. Plus I linked to its github as well so you can just use it as a script.

Comment: Here's screenfetch:  https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch

Answer (score 10):

This is really not that complex For model and memory, here's a 1 liner that works for every video card I've tested it on regardless of manufacturer (Intel, AMD, NVIDIA):

`GPU=$(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d ":" -f3);RAM=$(cardid=$(lspci | grep VGA |cut -d " " -f1);lspci -v -s $cardid | grep " prefetchable"| cut -d "=" -f2);echo $GPU $RAM`

**GPU=** All this bit does is grab the 3rd field from 'lspci' output filtered via 'grep' for VGA which corresponds to the video chip.

**RAM=** All this bit does is set variable `cardid` equal to the first field of output from `lspci` matching "VGA" and feeds that as a request for `-v` verbose output from `lspci` for that specific `-s` device, further filtering the output by `grep` for the string " prefetchable" as this contains the memory on the card itself (note the preceding space as we don't want to match "non-prefetchable" in our output.

**For clock rate on Intel integrated graphics (Tested on I3 and I5)**

execute the command `sudo find /sys -type f -name gt_cur* -print0 | xargs -0 cat`
This dives into the /sys tree to locate the gt_cur_freq_mhz
file which on my I3 is `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/gt_cur_freq_mhz` and prints the content. which in my case under extremely light load is `350` as in 350 MHz which corresponds to the minimum frequency found in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/gt_min_freq_mhz` and when running `glxgears` and `glmark2` results in 
`1050` as in 1050 MHz which corresponds to the maximum frequency found in `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/gt_max_freq_mhz`

**For clock rates on nvidia cards:**

`nvidia-smi -stats -d procClk` corresponds to the GPU clock
`nvidia-smi -stats -d memClk` corresponds to the memory clock.

Note: I am unable to test the above as my trusty GeForce 210 isn't supported and this works only on Kepler or newer GPUs as indicated by 
`nvidia-smi -stats --help'

I do not currently have any solutions for clock rate on AMD cards and do not have the hardware available for testing. I will however say that to the best of my knowledge the `aticonfig` mentioned in the accepted answer no longer exists and it appears that `nvclock` isn't available for anything since trusty.

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for only the names of the video cards on the machine, then simply use:

```
$ nvidia-smi --list-gpus
```

For some newer GPUs, this also lists the memory of each device.

Comment: to be even shorter: `$nvidia-smi -L`

Answer (score 8):

## Conky or Terminal Splash Screen

I use two methods to automatically display nVidia GPU and Intel iGPU information:

- Conky dynamically displays GPU information in real time
- `~/.bashrc` displays GPU information each time the terminal is opened

---

### Conky real time display

This example uses Conky to display current GPU (nVidia or Intel) stats in real time. Conky is a light weight system monitor popular among many Linux enthusiasts.

The display changes depending on if you booted after `prime-select intel` or `prime-select nvidia`.

#### Intel iGPU

[image: gpu temp intel.gif]

- The Intel iGPU shows as `Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU` with current frequency
- The Minimum frequency is `350` MHz and the Maximum is `1050` MHz

#### nVidia GPU

[image: gpu temp nvidia.gif]

- The nVidia GPU shows as `GeForce GTX970M` with current GPU frequency and temperature
- The Driver version, P-State and BIOS version are displayed
- The GPU load, RAM use, Power Consumption and RAM frequency is displayed

#### Conky Code

Here is the relevant Conky script for Intel iGPU and nVidia GPU:

```
#------------+
# Intel iGPU |
#------------+
${color orange}${hr 1}${if_match "intel" == "${execpi 99999 prime-select query}"}
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® Skylake GT2 HD 530 iGPU @${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_cur_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color}${goto 13}Min. Freq:${goto 120}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_min_freq_mhz)} MHz${color}${goto 210}Max. Freq:${alignr}${color green}${execpi .001 (cat /sys/class/drm/card1/gt_max_freq_mhz)} MHz
${color orange}${hr 1}${else}
#------------+
# Nvidia GPU |
#------------+
${color2}${voffset 5}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}@ ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.sm --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=temperature.gpu --format=csv,noheader)}°C
${color1}${voffset 5}Ver: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1} P-State: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=pstate --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}BIOS: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=vbios_version --format=csv,noheader)}
${color1}${voffset 5}GPU:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Ram:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.memory --format=csv,noheader)} ${color1}Pwr:${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader)} ${alignr}${color1}Freq: ${color green}${execpi .001 (nvidia-smi --query-gpu=clocks.mem --format=csv,noheader)}
${color orange}${hr 1}${endif}
```

---

#### `~/.bashrc` Terminal splash screen

This example modifies `~/.bashrc` to display information on a splash screen each time the terminal is opened or whenever you type `. .bashrc` at the shell prompt.

In addition to `neofetch` answered previously, there is `screenfetch` which looks a lot nicer (IMO). Plus another answer mentions he doesn't know how to get iGPU listed and this does it:

[image: ubuntu terminal splash.png]

For details on setup see: [Terminal splash screen with Weather, Calendar, Time & Sysinfo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020692/how-can-i-get-this-terminal-splash-screen)

In summary just for the bottom section with Ubuntu display containing GPU information (second last line) use:

```
sudo apt install screenfetch
screenfetch
```

You'll want to put the `screenfetch` command an the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file to have it appear every time you open the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Just to find the basics, according to https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#NVIDIA_Proprietary_Driver,

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

If you need more detail than that, see @knb's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/392944/118036) to this same question.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to have simple information, you could try [gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat). It is very good and simple.

[image: gpustat screenshot]

The author gives the following installation instructions:

> Install from PyPI:
>
> ```
> pip install gpustat
> ```
>
> To install the latest version (master branch) via
>   pip:
>
> ```
> pip install git+https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat.git@master
> ```
>
> If you
>   don't have root privilege, please try to install on user namespace:
>   `pip install --user`. Note that from v0.4, `gpustat.py` is no more a
>   zero-dependency executable. However, in rare cases you'll need a
>   single executable script (legacy), you can also try:
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wookayin/gpustat/v0.3.2/gpustat.py -O ~/.local/bin/gpustat chmod +x ~/.local/bin/gpustat    # Assuming ~/.local/bin is in your $PATH
> ```

Comment: Only NVIDIA supported.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a AMD Radeon Card, you may want to run the following commands

```
sudo update-pciids #optional command, requires internet
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

It should report something like this

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] [1002:9874] (rev c5)
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
```

Comment: This was also an issue solver for me with my NVIDIA card. Found this in the official CUDA installation guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation

Comment: The best answer! I have AMD Ryzen 7 6800u (onexplayer), Every tool shows just AMD/ATI Rembrandt. After this tip it shows Radeon 680M additionally. Kudos!

Answer (score 5):

For nvidia GPUs, `nvidia-smi` command is your friend.
See `man nvidia-smi` if you like to.

For listing GPUs use `nvidia-smi -L` (`nvidia-smi --list-gpus`),
`nvidia-smi -q` give information about the gpu and the running processes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this answer assumes you have a server with NVIDIA-GPUs. You have three ways:

1. To get just a short gist: `nvidia-smi`
2. To get a detailed one : `nvidia-smi -q`. You'll get multiple screens of detailed info if you more than 1 gpu.
3. Do a `ls /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/`. It'll display the GPU-bus location as folders. 
   Now, run the following command for each of the gpu bus locations. Fill `<gpu-id>` with bus-location: `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/<gpu_id>/information`

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Ubuntu on a Chromebook with crouton, the only one of the answers that will work is going to `chrome://gpu` in the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

For AMD based graphics card(GPU), you can use `radeon-profile` application to get detailed information about the cards. It provides temperature, clock, Vram usage etc. ([Github repository link](https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile))

Step1: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:radeon-profile/stable`

Step 2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install radeon-profile
```

Step 3: run `radeon-profile`

Output screenshots (I have two GPU cards, card0(integrated) and card1(discrete)):
[image: AMD integrated GPU]
[image: AMD Discrete GPU]

System specification:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 4600h
- GPU: AMD® Radeon rx 5600m

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1394351/922137)

Answer (score 1):

For the Intel GMA950 (comes with EeePC in particular) you can run:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 f0.b
```

which will return '00' for 200MHz, '01' for 250MHz or '03' for 400MHz. You may be able to apply the same principle to other Intel cards.

Comment: I'm getting 04. My GPU is 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Answer (score 1):

Use `lspci` , `lspci -v` to get basic info see [here](https://h-node.org/videocards/view/fr/1542/Intel-Corporation-Haswell-ULT-Integrated-Graphics-Controller--rev-09-).

In my case for ex once I run `lspci` and I have got :

```
dina@dina-X450LA:~$ lspci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all the information about the graphics processor, you can use the following command as specified by @greyfade.

```
> glxinfo
```

However, if the program `glxinfo` is currently not installed, you can install it by typing:

```
> sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

You will also have to enable the component called `universe`. Once this is done, `glxinfo` will list all the specifications related to the graphics processor in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Tested for GTX 1080Ti - For clock rates on nvidia card -

```
nvidia-smi stats -d procClk corresponds to the Core clock 
nvidia-smi stats -d memClk corresponds to the Memory clock
```

---

For monitoring every second -

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi stats -d procClk -c 1
```

---

For monitoring a subset of the devices every second -

```
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi stats -d procClk -c 1 -i 0,1
```

Based off on Elder Geek's answer with modifications to print every second to check for thermal throttling.
If your GPU is being throttled, the procClk will drop significantly.

Answer (score 1):

For checking the utilization of Intel GPUs there is `intel_gpu_top` available since xenial (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/intel-gpu-tools).

```
apt-get install intel-gpu-tools
```

There are just a few options available - see `man intel_gpu_top`.

Comment: ```$ intel_gpu_top -d pci
Failed to detect engines! (No such file or directory)
(Kernel 4.16 or newer is required for i915 PMU support.)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)``` for me on a ChromeOS Flex NUC

Answer (score 1):

Like in [Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/a/217481/137696), if you have Firefox: [about:support](http://about:support)

[image: firefox gpu intel 4000 linux]

Answer (score 1):

For my setup this is the cleanest:

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0));"
```

or

```
python -c "import uutils; gpu_name_otherwise_cpu(print_to_stdout=True);"
```

code:

```
def gpu_name_otherwise_cpu(print_to_stdout: bool = False):
    gpu_name_or_cpu = None
    try:
        gpu_name_or_cpu = torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
    except:
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        gpu_name_or_cpu = device
    print(f'{gpu_name_or_cpu=}') if print_to_stdout else None
    return gpu_name_or_cpu
```