# How to see what technologies a video card supports

Tags: graphics

I am looking for a way to check if a video card supports a technology. Either using an Open Source driver or a proprietary one, how can I check to see what video technologies a video card can handle. For example:

- Pixel Shader Version
- OpenGL Version
- OpenGL ES Version
- HDMI / DVI/ VGA Output
- GPU Speed
- Amount of Memory (Either On CPU, Board or PCIe card)
- Any other characteristics and video technologies that can be extracted from the video card.

For example, I have 2 computers. One has an Intel CPU with HD4000 using the open source drivers. The other one has an NVIDIA 560 ti video card using the 325 NVIDIA proprietary drivers. How can I see the mentioned characteristics for each of them.

Comment: You can easily fetch the info within Unity if you're using the Wikipedia lens. Other than that [this question seems appropriate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-gpu-info).

Comment: The Wikipedia lens is smart but let's assume there is no internet and the user does not know the video card. For the link it is also good but does not tell me for example, what Pixel Shader the video card supports, What type of output does it offer and other similar info.

Comment: I think this needs three answers from three users (intel, ati, nvidia) and a someone make a utility given these answers request.  I'm not sure the utility you're after exists.

Comment: @CallmeV You know what guys, am going to close this for the moment I am sure there has to be someway of grabbing this kind of information. Thanks CallmeV & Uri.

Comment: Guys could no find a single one that offered something that told the user if his/her video card support Pixel Shader, video Output types supported and other video characteristics. Opened the question again to give a chance to others that are curious about it.

Comment: Can't you just google the cards and read the specs?

Comment: on the manufactures web site you can always search for your model and see what technology it support. Haven't you tried that already?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Google Chrome and go to URL *chrome://gpu*

*Report generated looks like this:*

**Graphics Feature Status**

```
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
3D CSS: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
CSS Animation: Accelerated
Flash 3D: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL multisampling: Hardware accelerated
Texture Sharing: Hardware accelerated
Video: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
```

**Problems Detected**

```
Accelerated 2d canvas is unstable in Linux at the moment
Stage3D is not supported on Linux: 129848
Accelerated video decode is unavailable on Mac and Linux: 137247, 133828
NVIDIA linux drivers are unstable when using multiple Open GL contexts and with low memory: 145600
```

**Driver Bug Workarounds**

```
 ...
```

**Version Information**

**Driver Information**

solution found here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/217481/9881