# Getting GPU Information

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, gpu

I have a Dell Laptop. I Want to find GPU Info (Ubuntu 14.04).

```
 lshw -C display

 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

THe `about:gpu` tab in chrome says:

```
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x1002, DEVICE= 0x6604
GPU1    VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x1616 *ACTIVE*
```

Now, I am confused. I bought the laptop with a AMD Radeon 2GB Video card.

Nowhere I see it.

How to get that information?

Output of command: lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3d|vga'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 066f
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
--
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Strange, `lshw` should have printed 2 `*-display` entries if you have a separate graphics card. Can you run it as root again (`sudo lshw -C display`) please and compare the results?

Comment: Can you also please add the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3d|vga'`?

Comment: @ByteCommander hi, i have added it. thx.

Comment: Not only the lspci output, the "GPU0    VENDOR = 0x1002, DEVICE= 0x6604" in Chrome is also showing the AMD GPU, 1002 is the vendor code for AMD, 6604 is the specific card id.

Answer (score 2):

The command `glxinfo` will give you all available OpenGL information for the graphics processor, including its vendor name, if the drivers are correctly installed.

To get clock speed information, there is no standard tool.

1. For ATI/AMD GPUs, `aticonfig --odgc` will fetch the clock rates, and
   `aticonfig --odgt` will fetch the temperature data.
2. For NVIDIA GPUs, the `nvclock` program will fetch the same information.

I am not aware of an equivalent tool for the open source drivers or for Intel or other GPUs.

Other information on the hardware can be fetched from the `lspci` and `lshw` tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can get detailed information about AMD graphics cards using `radeon-profile`([Github repository link](https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile)). It provides temperature, clock, Vram usage etc.

Step1: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:radeon-profile/stable`

Step 2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install radeon-profile
```

Step 3: run `radeon-profile`

Output screenshots (I have two GPU cards, card0(integrated) and card1(discrete)):
[image: AMD integrated GPU]
[image: AMD Discrete GPU]

System specification:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- CPU: AMD® Ryzen 5 4600h
- GPU: AMD® Radeon rx 5600m