# How to identify AMD graphic card model on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I am trying to install the latest graphic card driver. So I need to know the exact model of the card I am using, without opening my PC case, checking the model physically. I tried:

`lspci | grep AMD | grep VGA`

which getting the following result

`VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev c1)`

The result is not bad, but for installing the driver the result is not good enough since 5700 and 5700XT have different drivers. So my question is, is there a way to know the exact model?

Comment: does [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/) help at all?

Comment: Yes, the `Settings`->`About` dialog has the information I want, Thanks

Comment: I've added that as an answer, perhaps you would be kind enough to [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it to help others find a solution in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Gnome 3 based distros (Ubuntu by default) open `settings` and click on the details and choose `About`:

[image]

[reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tell-which-graphics-vga-card-installed/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `radeon-profile` application.

[I answered it here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1394351/922137)

Output screenshot:

[image]