# How to get second and third GPU working on 18.04

Tags: graphics

I got one NVIDIA 1050 GPU installed ... load the 390 version of the drivers and go it going. I added a second and third NVIDIA 1050 GPU ... but they do not seem to be recognized by Ubuntu.

Comment: I used a riser card to connect the gpu to the pcieX1 slots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}` [like explained by knb](https://askubuntu.com/a/392944/247973)?

It would add some useful output to further diagnose the issue.

Comment: I removed the second GPU ... but I entered the above command and got the following:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 610 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd HD Graphics 610
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
 Memory at 2ffe000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
 Memory at 2fe0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
 Memory at ee000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
 Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
 I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at ef000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

Comment: THE 1050 2GB GPU works in the pcieX16 slot. I moved the card from the pcieX16 slot to another pcieX1 slot and restarted and nothing shows on the screen. I put the GPU back in the pcieX16 slot and restarte and screen appears and all is working as it should again. Is something needed for the pcieX1 slots to start working?

Comment: Most of the time PCIe X1 ports are physically shorter than PCIe X16 slots. Your card would require a PCIe X16 sized slot to plug in.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your motherboard and CPU?

Comment: If you still have the issue, try adding all relevant information as an edit to your original question. If you use the PCIe X1 with a riser; does your GPU have adequate power delivery?