# Dedicated GPU increases idling temps

Tags: drivers

When I'm using the integrated Intel uhd GPU the idle temps of my cpu are around 40-45 C.
But when I switch to my Nvidia GTX 1050, the idle temps for both CPU and GPU jump up to the 47-51 C range, and I'm concerned about this rise in temperature. I know the operating temps are still in the normal range but I'm concerned about the sudden rise. Is this normal???
Thanks 
P.S. If this is relevant, the laptop I'm using is a MSI GL63 8RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rise in temperature is normal. The nVidia GTX 970M for example uses 24 watts which is quite a bit in computing terms:

[image: nvidia temperature.png]

Turning off the nVidia GPU with `sudo prime-select intel` will reduce heat by 5 to 10 degrees but there is really no cause for concern unless running on battery. In this case turning off the nVidia GPU would benefit battery life.

Even at the displayed temperatures there is no heat on the keyboard and fans (there are two one for CPU and one for GPU) cannot be heard.

To summarize if your situation is like above conky display there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I was starting to get worried. But now I'm happy that there is no problem with my laptop.

Comment: Also, I'm a beginner in ubuntu, so can you please tell me how to get this report like the one in the photo.

Comment: @AmanSavaria It's not a report, an on-screen system monitor called `conky` that refreshes every 2 seconds but you can set any refresh interval you like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info/1026234#1026234 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance/1047763#1047763 plus just search on `conky` here on this website