# Showing ID of GPUs that are currently being used

Tags: command-line, gpu

I have 4 GPU cards in my server, I can see which ones are running by nvidia-smi and check if memory is full, but I want to automate this process, is there any commands that can return e.g. GPU device ID = 0,1,2 is being used, instead of eye-ball checking the nvidia-smi? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.