# My ubuntu does not recognize Nvidia card

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

After saving many things (including the fact that my ubuntu *does not normally boot* -> solved that temporarily by erasing quiet splash and adding acpi=off in the grub option), I could *finally!* install ubuntu 20.04 in my machine. (I had to repair the grub and the partitioning of my hard disk is horrible and doing it just like that)

Anyway, now I have a ubuntu 20 system on my hard drive. The next thing I have to solve is that this system does not recognize my Nivida card: GTX 1080ti GP102.

Obviously `nividia-sim` is not installed .

The thing is I went to "software & updates" and in the "Additional Drivers" there is nothing. (it says "No additional drivers available"). Originally I thought this is the place where the drivers could be downloaded.

I don't want to mess things more than they are now So I ask directly *What should I do and in what order?*

Comment: I don't think I can help you too far (since I'm not an expert), but your computer is plugged into a monitor?  Are you using the video port from your Nvidia card or the on-board video port?  Of course, should be the former.  And, in some cases, you might want to go to BIOS to disable the latter.  Confirming this would be the first step...

Comment: Well, the only way to connect my monitor is through the nvidia card. Howeve I am currently trying some tools and none recognize the card. It is like it does not exist. I am no expert either but I head there si no on-board video port...

Comment: I am checking my BIOS. Where is the info on the card supposed to appear?

Comment: If the only way to connect to your monitor is the Nvidia card, then it is "working", at least.  Some desktops have a built-in output for the video display.  Then you add on or buy an NVidia card and you should disable the former explicitly (unless you wanted dual monitor and your NVidia card has only one output).  But that doesn't seem to be the case with you.

Comment: You can look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info).  It is a bit out-dated, but the `lspci` and `lshw` commands are still valid.  And it is `nvidia-smi`.  See if any of this turns up something.  If it's available for you, I'd try to install the drivers via the GUI (i.e., "Software & Updates") and not manually via `apt`.  I recently had an issue where I couldn't get all the dependencies with `apt`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer your first question -- if you have just one output for display, then it's probably not in your BIOS.  It's not in every BIOS, so don't look for it for too long.  And it does vary from computer to computer.

Comment: I already tried that. Unfortunately it gives no info. I am booting my PC with the apci=off option. And apparently that turns off the PCI card. I changed the card and the things got worse. Now I have no output at all :(

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is.  I think you'd want to make sure this isn't a hardware problem.  Like neither the card nor the slot has an issue.  With recent versions of Ubuntu, I haven't had to tweak the grub options...so I'm afraid I don't know what else you can try...