# Is my integrated graphic card working?

Tags: drivers, gpu

The result of the below command is shown below:

Command:

`lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`

Output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4c8a] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Command:

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

Output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8a (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7d16
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 4c11 (rev 01)
```

The result of the
Is my integrated gpu working? I am using Ubuntu 20.04. My CPU is Intel Core i7 11700K which comes with UHD 750 GPU. I don't have any discrete graphic card.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I added more info

Comment: If you're able to see this web site on your screen, then your internal Intel video card is working. Why do you ask?

Comment: The output looks wrong to me.

Comment: And that's ok or not ? Did you see this : [How to get the GPU info?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with mesa-utils :

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Enter this command in your terminal :

```
glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
```

Result :

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: **example of graphical card**)
```

In the example above and on a PC with two graphics cards, the **example of graphical card** is used.

You can also try with lshw :

```
sudo apt install lshw
lshw -C display
```

or with lspci :

```
sudo update-pciids
lspci | egrep "3D|VGA"
```

Comment: I used ``lspci | egrep "3D|VGA"
`` and the output is ``00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] (rev 04)
``  This means my UHD 750 graphic card is working?

Comment: The result of ``clinfo`` is  ``Number of platforms      0``.  How can I make my pc see the gpu from ``clinfo`` command?

Comment: I used these commands `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME` and `sudo usermod -a -G render $LOGNAME`